# ASP vb compilation error 800A03EA

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, compiler-errors

i'm not an ASP guy but i've inherited an asp project recently. my task is pretty much to skin it up and make all the functionality built over the last 10 years simply work better visually and experientially for the user.

so far so good until today. i'm getting the following error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'

Syntax error

/test/calsearchmember.asp, line 3

if ((Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item >=0) && (Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item<=31))
---------------------------------------------^
```

i have copied the site into a test directory and have been making changes there. this calendar search function works fine on the main site, but not here in the subdirectory and i hadn't changed anything to the file producing the error.

any ideas? thanks!

---

i wanted to share some more of the code itself to help paint a better picture of the problem.

here's how the file is called:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--#include file="sidebarclientscript.inc"-->
</script>
```

and here is the first bit of code (in which the error is being flagged):

```
<%
if ((Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item >=0) && (Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item<=31))
{
    var sql;
    var date = Request.Form("calsearchmonth") + "/" + Request.Form("dateToToggle") + "/" + Request.Form("calsearchyear")

    if (Request.Form("bNewStateOpen").Item == "true")
    {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM OpenDates WHERE MemberId = ";
        sql += Request.Form("calsearchmember");
        sql += " AND DateValue(OpenDate) = DateValue('";
        sql += date;
        sql += "') AND TimeValue(OpenDate) = ";

        if (Request.Form("calsearchPM").Item == "1")
            sql += "TimeValue('12:00:00 PM')";
        else
            sql += "''";

        //Response.Write(sql);
        var rs = db.Execute(sql);
        if (rs.EOF)
        {
            sql = "INSERT INTO OpenDates (MemberId, OpenDate) VALUES ("
            sql += Request.Form("calsearchmember").Item
            sql += ", '"
            sql += date;
            if (Request.Form("calsearchPM").Item == "1")
                sql += " 12:00:00 PM";
            sql += "')"

            //Response.Write("<BR>"+sql);
            db.Execute(sql);
        }
    }
           %>`
```

hope this helps clarify things a bit more. thanks again for your input and help

Comment: thanks for the idea but i had already unfortunately tried that without any result besides another error:

"Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f9'
Expected 'Then'"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the default language changed from JScript to VBScript, so change it back to JScript.

**IIS 5:** (should also apply to 6)

Management Console → right click website → Properties → Home Directory tab → Configuration button → Options → Under "Default ASP language" type JScript and confirm.

**IIS 7.5:**

Management Console → IIS → ASP → Compilation → Script Language → Type "JScript" and confirm.

Screenshots for 7.5 to make it more clear:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. i've just updated the original post to show more code. with the new information in mind do you think this is still the issue? and, if so, how is it that the root directory isn't affected, just my `/test/` directory?

Comment: @John that's definitely JScript. Change your script tag to: `<script runat="server" language="JScript">` and it should work.

Comment: just tried that and got this error: `Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0234'

Invalid include directive

/test/mainheader.inc, line 20

Server side include directives may not be present in script blocks. Please use the SRC= attribute of the <SCRIPT> tag.`  and then when i put that include file in the `src` it get the following error: `Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03ea'

Syntax error

/test/sidebarclientscript.inc, line 1

<%
-^`

Comment: and here is the page in question if it helps any: http://ioaofficials.com/test/calsearchmember.asp

Answer (score 0):

You also need a `then` at the end:

```
if ((Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item >=0) and (Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item<=31)) then
```

Comment: sorry, i should've notated more in my comment above. it's using curly braces, so `if ((Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item >=0) and (Request.Form("dateToToggle").Item<=31)) { }`

Comment: OK - it's beginning to look like you don't have a VBScript file there. That's looking like a JScript file. Try reversing the changes suggested so far and simply change the page directive to <% @LANGUAGE="JSCRIPT" %>

Comment: good idea. it is an asp file that is included in between `<script>` tags and then jumps in and out of js and vb (i think). i'll revisit the file later tonight or early tomorrow and hit you back. it still doesn't account, however, for the sudden breaking on this backup site without any changes being made to it. :\